# How can I prove if 2 datasets are separable or not?

Tags: classification, separation

I want to create a classification model, derived from real spectral measurements. My data is in the form of samples x features. The number of features is 424 and the number of samples is in the order of tens of thousands for each specimen. By using e.g. a non linear SVM classifier, I can see that some specimens are differentiated very well and some others are confused one with each other. By looking at the raw data, the misclassified ones are indeed very similar.

Is there any official metric that can tell if two datasets are separable or not? I would like to know this to see if there is any point in trying furtherly to improve the classification results or not.

Thank you a lot in advance!

Comment: I suppose you mean to say 'linearly' separable? if so, please edit!   In that case, try with a SVM (support vector machine).

Comment: I want to know if they are separable, meaning if there is any point or not in trying different classification approaches (linear or non-linear). Is there any way to prove if they are non-separable?

Comment: Not before you have defined clearly what you mean by "non-separable"!

Comment: By "non-separable" I mean something like this: If I have two sets of samples  and want to assign them to 2 different classes, but whatever classifier I use, they cannot be classified correctly, since their raw data are almost identical... Is there any way of proving this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your definition of "separable", any data set is separable. E.g., if you have 10000 observations you can add a qualitative predictor to your model, an observation id, that has 10000 distinct levels. Then it won't be a problem to obtain perfect classification.

In other words, the "separability" you are referring to very much depends on the available predictors. It is possible that, apart from the trivial solution above, there are some meaningful predictors that result in perfect classification, but you don't know what they are.